# Ti.Admob Build.py error

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Followed the standard instructions:

### INSTALL YOUR MODULE

1. Run `build.py` which creates your distribution
2. cd to `/Library/Application Support/Titanium`
3. extract your zip into this folder

I am getting the following error:

> /Users/Michael/Downloads/ti.admob-master/ios/Classes/TiAdmobView.h:8:9:
> fatal error:
>
> 'TiUIView.h' file not found
>
> #import "TiUIView.h"
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> The following build commands failed:
>
> CompileC
> build/admob.build/Release-iphoneos/admob.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TiAdmobViewProxy.o
> Classes/TiAdmobViewProxy.m normal armv7 objective-c
> com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler   CompileC
> build/admob.build/Release-iphoneos/admob.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TiAdmobModule.o
> Classes/TiAdmobModule.m normal arm64 objective-c
> com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (2 failures) xcodebuild
> failed michaels-MacBook-Pro:ios Michael$

Answer (score 1):

Check your titanium.xcconfig and be sure you are correctly referencing a compatible and existing TiSDK version.